# Node.js child_process only successfully run command with sudo added in Ubuntu 16

Tags: node.js, child-process, chmod, spawn

I am unable to run a script using `child_process`. The same command works on Terminal or when I add `sudo` in front of it. Adding `sudo` is not an option as I want it to run automatically. Below is my code:

```
var cmd_saga = 'grid_spline 4 ' +
    '-TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "' + shapefile + '" -FIELD "' + short_param + '" -METHOD 1 ' +
    '-EPSILON 0.0001 -LEVEL_MAX 14 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.01 -TARGET_USER_FITS 1 ' +
    '-TARGET_OUT_GRID "' + saga_path + '"';

const { spawnSync } = require( 'child_process' );
const sag = spawnSync('saga_cmd', cmd_saga.split(' '));

console.log( `stderr: ${sag.stderr.toString()}` );
console.log( `stdout: ${sag.stdout.toString()}` );
```

Below is the error message when I it runs it without `sudo`:

```
stderr: Error: input file [/home/user/apps/app/temp/ApDy5Icw0anTkX7-AAAD/1599095530195.shp]
Error: Points

stdout: ____________________________

   #####   ##   #####    ##
  ###     ###  ##       ###
   ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
    ### ##### ##    # #####
 ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.1

____________________________
library path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/
library name: libgrid_spline
library     : Spline Interpolation
tool        : Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation
author      : O.Conrad (c) 2006
processors  : 24 [24]
____________________________

Load shapes: /home/user/apps/app/temp/ApDy5Icw0anTkX7-AAAD/1599095530195.shp...
failed

Usage: saga_cmd grid_spline 4 [-SHAPES <str>] [-FIELD <str>] [-TARGET_DEFINITION <str>] [-TARGET_USER_SIZE <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_FITS <str>] [-TARGET_TEMPLATE <str>] [-TARGET_OUT_GRID <str>] [-METHOD <str>] [-EPSILON <double>] [-LEVEL_MAX <num>]
  -SHAPES:<str>                 Points
    Shapes (input)
  -FIELD:<str>                  Attribute
    Table field
  -TARGET_DEFINITION:<str>      Target Grid System
    Choice
    Available Choices:
    [0] user defined
    [1] grid or grid system
    Default: 0
  -TARGET_USER_SIZE:<double>    Cellsize
    Floating point
    Minimum: 0.000000
    Default: 1.000000
  -TARGET_USER_XMIN:<double>    Left
    Floating point
    Default: 0.000000
  -TARGET_USER_XMAX:<double>    Right
    Floating point
    Default: 100.000000
  -TARGET_USER_YMIN:<double>    Bottom
    Floating point
    Default: 0.000000
  -TARGET_USER_YMAX:<double>    Top
    Floating point
    Default: 100.000000
  -TARGET_USER_FITS:<str>       Fit
    Choice
    Available Choices:
    [0] nodes
    [1] cells
    Default: 0
  -TARGET_TEMPLATE:<str>        Target System
    Grid (optional input)
  -TARGET_OUT_GRID:<str>        Target Grid
    Grid (output)
  -METHOD:<str>                 Method
    Choice
    Available Choices:
    [0] without B-spline refinement
    [1] with B-spline refinement
    Default: 1
  -EPSILON:<double>             Threshold Error
    Floating point
    Minimum: 0.000000
    Default: 0.000100
  -LEVEL_MAX:<num>              Maximum Level
    Integer
    Minimum: 1
    Maximum: 14
    Default: 11

grid_spline 4 -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "/home/user/apps/app/temp/ApDy5Icw0anTkX7-AAAD/1599095530195.shp" -FIELD "chlorophyl" -METHOD 1 -EPSILON 0.0001 -LEVEL_MAX 14 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.01 -TARGET_USER_FITS 1 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "/home/user/apps/app/temp/ApDy5Icw0anTkX7-AAAD/1599095530195.sdat"
```

I have also made the folder and the file excutable with `sudo chmod 755` and `chmod +x *`

Is there any way to make it run without `sudo`? I am open to using any other library that works.

Comment: What is the error when you try running it via node? Are you running node in the same terminal as you run the commands?

Comment: @Matt Good question. I have updated my question with error message.